# Adicionar página ao Google

Tags: html, google

Existe alguma `<meta>` tag que faça com que o Google procure meu site e mostre dessa forma ? ou é algum script desenvolvido pelo Google para melhorar a forma de pesquisar os site ?
[image: modo de fazer]

Comment: Não, muito diferente !

Comment: Esta indexação é feita de forma automática e só aparece quando a procura é altamente relevante para um determinado site.

Comment: A resposta de lá responde sua pergunta sim, logo, é uma duplicata. Não precisa ser a mesma pergunta, e sim, que a resposta para ambas seja a mesma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No momento, os **sitelinks** são automatizados. No entanto, existem práticas recomendadas que podem ser seguidas para melhorar a qualidade dos seus sitelinks. Por exemplo, para os **links internos** do seu site, use textos âncora e textos com atributo *alt* informativos, compactos e sem repetições.

Para obter mais ajuda sobre sitelinks acesse [esse tópico](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=pt-BR).

Para dicas relacionadas à link internos e textos âncora acesse [esse tópico](http://www.agenciamestre.com/seo/linkagem-interna-texto-ancora/).